# Can I use MariaDB as a replication slave for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication

I've been a MySQL user/administrator for many years and I've been considering a switch to MariaDB. We have a statement-replicated setup with a MySQL slave and I've been thinking that one way to ease-into a MariaDB environment might be to swap the slave out for MariaDB until we're comfortable, then switch the master to MariaDB.

Is that something that is possible? I suspect it is, since the replication interface is fairly simple, especially for a statement-replicated setup.

Is that something that makes any sense?

***UPDATE***
I happen to be using MySQL 5.5 as the master and MySQL 5.6 as the replicated slave in my current environment, just in case that has any bearing on anything. But I'm curious if different versions might be better or worse for a mixed-vendor setup.

Comment: Older version on Master + newer version of Slave is strongly recommended.  MariaDB on slave to a Master running Oracle's MySQL is more likely to work than the opposite.

Comment: Any solution for mariadb master, mysql slave?

Comment: You should ask your question separately to get a better answer. The short answer is that MariaDB has a nice compatibility-matrix of versions where it should be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and probably makes sense. See e.g. [Replicating from MySQL Master to MariaDB Slave](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-up-replication/#replicating-from-mysql-master-to-mariadb-slave). So with MySQL 5.5 as the master, you can use MariaDB 5.5 or later as the slave.

Comment: Yes You can, but you can't use GTID repliction. Because mariadb and mysql have different GTID method

Comment: MySQL 5.5 doesn't have GTID replication so it's a non-issue :)

Comment: FWIW, I ended up running MySQL 5.5 master and MariaDB 10.1 slave for quite a while and all was well. GTID wasn't an issue, since MySQL 5.5 hadn't yet diverged. MySQL 5.5 isn't on the [list here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#replication-compatibility), but it is indeed compatible as a master database for MariaDB replication slaves.